# how to use an extern function in dynamic library

Tags: xcode, shared-libraries, dynamic-library

I use Xcode build a dynamic library:

In test.h

```
extern void extern_func(void);
@interface test : NSObject
@end
```

In test.m

```
@implementation test
+ (void)load {
   extern_func();
}
@end
```

When compiling, the compiler complains：Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: _extern_func

I tried adding the parameter -fPIC to other c flags, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.